# Код не работает на хостинге

Tags: php

Я только учусь.

Написал код php, на Денвере работает, на хостинге ругается. Может кто подскажет, что не так?

```
function tab()
{
    ob_start();

    $dir = opendir("/files/"); //путь к файлам
    while ($file = readdir($dir)) {
        if (($file != ".") && ($file != "..") && ($file != "")) {
            $cat   = "$file"; // строка, подлежащая частичной замене
            $r     = array(
                "yo",
                "ye",
                "ts",
                "ch",
                "sh",
                "shch",
                "yu",
                "ya",
                "a",
                "b",
                "v",
                "g",
                "d",
                "e",
                "j",
                "z",
                "i",
                "y",
                "k",
                "l",
                "m",
                "n",
                "o",
                "p",
                "r",
                "s",
                "t",
                "u",
                "f",
                "e",
                "_",
                "h"
            ); // что менять ("a" и "b");
            $r2    = array(
                "ё",
                "ё",
                "ц",
                "ч",
                "ш",
                "щ",
                "ю",
                "я",
                "а",
                "б",
                "в",
                "г",
                "д",
                "е",
                "г",
                "з",
                "и",
                "и",
                "к",
                "л",
                "м",
                "н",
                "о",
                "п",
                "р",
                "с",
                "т",
                "у",
                "ф",
                "Э",
                " ",
                "х"
            ); // на что менять ("0" и "1");
            $trans = str_ireplace($r, $r2, $cat);

            echo '<img src="/themes/present/images/PostCategoryIcon.png" WIDTH="50" HEIGHT="50" alt=""><a href="/files/' . $file . '">' . basename("$trans", "зип") . PHP_EOL . zip . '</a><br>';

        }
    }

    closedir($dir);
    $result = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    echo iconv('windows-1251', 'utf-8', $result);

}
add_shortcode('gitar_pro', 'tab');
```

Comment: а текста ошибки не будет?

Comment: А по конкретнее текст ошибки?

Comment: @tagra комментарии пишем в комментарии. В следующий раз будет минус

Answer (score 2):

Вполне возможно, что ошибка может быть здесь:

```
$dir = opendir ("/files/");
```

Если хостинг на Linux, то все, начинающееся со "/", система будет понимать как абсолютный путь, искать соответствующую директорию. Для решения предложу использовать функцию так:

```
$dir = opendir ("./files/");
$dir = opendir ("files/");
```

Если не там, то ошибочку то хоть покажите.

Comment: Вот .basename("$trans", "зип").PHP_EOL.zip. строка, если ее убрать слова выводятся нормально, а так коверкает все. Ну и кодировку изменил, а часть кода отвечающую за смену кодировки убрал.

Answer (score 0):

**basename("$trans", "зип").PHP_EOL.zip** - убрал эту строку из кода.

И привел все в правильной кодировке **utf-8 без bom**

И выкинул строки из программы отвечающие за перемену кодировки.